# How to pickle a scapy packet?

Tags: python, pickle, scapy

I need to pickle a `scapy` packet. Most of the time this works, but sometimes the pickler complains about a function object. As a rule of thumb: ARP packets pickle fine. Some UDP packets are problematic.

Comment: Background is usage in conjunction with the `multiprocessing` module. It requires objects to be pickleable if you want to transfer them through a `Queue`.

Comment: Could someone answer this question, so I can award the bounty?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My solution (as inspired by the scapy mailing list) is as follows:

```
class PicklablePacket:
    """A container for scapy packets that can be pickled (in contrast
    to scapy packets themselves)."""
    def __init__(self, pkt):
        self.contents = bytes(pkt)
        self.time = pkt.time

    def __call__(self):
        """Get the original scapy packet."""
        pkt = scapy.Ether(self.contents)
        pkt.time = self.time
        return pkt
```

Anywhere I wish to pass a `scapy` `Packet` through a `Queue` I simply wrap it in a `PicklablePacket` and `__call__` it afterwards. I am not aware of data that is not retained this way. However this approach only works with `Ethernet` packets. (All packets sniffed on a regular NIC (not WLAN) are Ethernet.) It could probably be extended to work for other types, too.

Comment: Thanks for posting back. While I didn't need your exact solution, it helped me find my own.

Answer (score 4):

If by pickle you mean generically serialize you can always use the pcap import/export methods: [rdpcap and wrpcap](http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/files/scapydoc.pdf).

```
wrpcap("pkt.pcap",pkt)
pkt = rdpcap("pkt.pcap")
```

Or you could start up your process and grab the packets in another process. If there is some pattern you can match, say a known port or source IP tcpdump will work:

```
tcpdump -i eth0 -w FOO.pcap host 172.20.33.12 and \(udp or arp\)
```

You can then read the generated pcap in as above:

```
pkts = rdpcap('FOO.pcap')
```

Comment: 1) I am talking about 500 packets per second.

Comment: 2) This method actually looses data. For instance the timestamp is rounded. This is not necessarily a problem, but has to be taken into account.

Comment: Can scapy even push out 500 packets per second? I've found that when sending packets it's much less than that. You could always run a tcpdump in another terminal.

Comment: Scapy can. See comment on other answer.

Comment: You could pass a reference to a file in the queue. strings are pickleable.

Comment: Sorry, creating a file for each packet is a bad joke in terms of performance. If I wouldn't care about performance I could use `threading` instead of `multiprocessing` and wouldn't have to pickle at all.

Answer (score 3):

(This is more for reference, so no votes expected)

The Scapy list scapy.ml@secdev.org is well-monitored and tends to be very responsive.  If you don't get answers here, try there as well.

Comment: Oh that's where communication goes on? The issue tracker seems pretty inactive. At least one of my bugs stayed there for half a year without any response.

Comment: as a side note, 500 packets per second might be more than Scapy handles as well.  It's designed for flexibility not speed :)  Ask on the list.  I don't really use it much, so I am no expert.

Comment: Actually I can confirm, that scapy handles 500 packets per second very well. Granted I use more than one thread and (after this question) more than one process.

Answer (score 1):

As inspired by this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16626429/python-cpickle-pickling-lambda-functions) one can use the [dill](http://trac.mystic.cacr.caltech.edu/project/pathos/wiki/dill) library (or others like sPickle etc - see [pypi search pickle](https://pypi.python.org/pypi?:action=search&term=pickle&submit=search)) to save scapy packets. E.g. Install dill using `sudo easy_install dill` or `sudo pip install dill`. Here's a basic usage scenario:

```
import dill as pickle
# E.g. Dump an array of packets stored in variable mypackets to a file
pickle.dump(mypackets, open('mypackets.dill-pickle', 'w'))
# Restore them from the file
mypackets = pickle.load(open('mypackets.dill-pickle', 'rb'))
```

Also one can of course just use scapy's native functions to dump the packets to a pcap file (readable by tcpdump/wireshark etc) - if one just has an array of packets:

```
wrpcap("packets_array.pcap",packets_array)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can monkeypatch the `Packet` class and inject `__getstate__` and `__setstate__` methods that convert the function in the object from and to a picklable representation. See [here](http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html#pickling-and-unpickling-normal-class-instances) for details.

```
def packet_getstate(self):
    # todo

def packet_setstate(self, state):
    # todo

from scapy.packet import Packet
Packet.__getstate__ = packet_getstate
Packet.__setstate__ = packet_setstate
```

Comment: This is kind of obvious to me. The non-obvious part is the todo part.

Comment: Interactively inspecting a `Packet` object that fails pickling (`pprint.pprint(packet.__dict__)`) would easily show what the function is, if it's a lambda, a function or an instance method. Do you already know what kind of function is?

Comment: The full traceback is too long for a comment, but you can easily reproduce that yourself. The final line is: pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <function <lambda> at 0x8bb2bc4>: it's not found as scapy.layers.inet.<lambda>

Answer (score 0):

To get the PicklabePacket class to work with scapy 3.0.0 you can use this class definition:

```
class PicklablePacket:
"""A container for scapy packets that can be pickled (in contrast
to scapy packets themselves).
This works for python 3.5.1 and scapy 3.0.0 """

def __init__(self, pkt):
    self.__contents = pkt.__bytes__()
    self.__time = pkt.time

def __call__(self):
    """Get the original scapy packet."""
    pkt = scapy.all.Ether(self.__contents)
    pkt.time = self.__time
    return pkt
```