# App Engine Lambda function limitation in Deferred Tasks

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7, lambda

App Engine documentation states that you should not use [lambda functions with the deferred library](https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/deferred).

1) Does this limitation only apply to functions that use the [lambda keyword](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#lambda-expressions)? Or does it also limit passing functions to the deferred task?

```
def formatA(a):
  return a.upper()

def formatB(b):
  return b.capitalize()

def applyFormat(elements, format_funcs):
   for i, element in enumerate(elements):
      formatted_element = format_funcs[i](element)

deferred.defer(applyFormat, (a,b), (normalizeA, normalizeB))
```

2) Does this limitation also apply to task queues as well?

3) Why? Is this because lambda functions cannot be pickled?

Answer (score 0):

After looking around a bit, I've come up with answers.  First, it looks like I was conflating two things: limitations on what you can call from the deferred library and limitations on the arguments you can send.

There is a limitation on calling lambda functions.

> You can't call lambda functions (but you probably wouldn't want to
>   anyway).

meaning that the following would not work.

```
deferred.defer(lambda x: x.upper(), x)
```

At the same time, there is a limitation that the arguments to the called function must be pickable. There is a limited set of functions that are pickable and lambda functions are not included. ([What can be pickled and unpickled?](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html#what-can-be-pickled-and-unpickled), [Pickling lambda functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16626429/python-cpickle-pickling-lambda-functions))

So answering my questions:

1. Lambda functions will fail as arguments to the deferred library.  So will most functions unless they are functions defined at the top of a module.
2. The limitation for calling a lambda function does not apply to task queues. With task queues, you're doing a post to a URL, so you need to set up a request handler and that request handler would be able to call lambda functions to its heart's content.  However, there is still the limitation that arguments to the task queue need to be serialized for the http POST, so chances are functions probably aren't something you want to pass anyway.
3. Yes, see above.