# dill vs cPickle speed difference

Tags: python, lambda, pickle, dill

I am trying to serialize thousands of objects and some of these objects are lambda objects.

Since `cPickle` doesn't work for lambdas, I tried using `dill`. However, the drop in computational speed is more than 10 times when unpickleing (or undilling (?)). Looking through the source, it seems that `dill` uses `pickle` internally which might be the reason for the speed drop.

Is there another option for me that combine the best of both modules?

EDIT: The most significant speed drop is during unpickleing.

Comment: check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16626757/5741205)

Comment: The problem, as I stated in my question, is that `dill` is too slow compared to cPickle.

Comment: "_PiCloud-serialized objects can be de-serialized using the normal pickle/cPickle load and loads functions._", so i thought it could help you if your `serialization / desiralization` ratio is `<< 1`

Comment: Ah sorry. I just clarified in the question that the significant speed drop is during desiralization.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

I'm the `dill` author.  Yes, `dill` is slower typically, but that's the penalty you pay for more robust serialization. If you are serializing a lot of classes and functions, then you might want to try one of the `dill` variants in `dill.settings`  If you use `byref=True` then `dill` will pickle several objects by reference (which is faster then the default).  Other settings trade off picklibility for speed in selected objects.

```
In [1]: import dill

In [2]: f = lambda x:x

In [3]: %timeit dill.loads(dill.dumps(f))
1000 loops, best of 3: 286 us per loop

In [4]: dill.settings['byref'] = True

In [5]: %timeit dill.loads(dill.dumps(f))
1000 loops, best of 3: 237 us per loop

In [6]: dill.settings
Out[6]: {'byref': True, 'fmode': 0, 'protocol': 2, 'recurse': False}

In [7]: dill.settings['recurse'] = True

In [8]: %timeit dill.loads(dill.dumps(f))
1000 loops, best of 3: 408 us per loop

In [9]: class Foo(object):
   ...:     x = 1
   ...:     def bar(self, y):
   ...:         return y + self.x
   ...:     

In [10]: g = Foo()

In [11]: %timeit dill.loads(dill.dumps(g))
10000 loops, best of 3: 87.6 us per loop

In [12]: dill.settings['recurse'] = False

In [13]: %timeit dill.loads(dill.dumps(g))
10000 loops, best of 3: 87.4 us per loop

In [14]: dill.settings['byref'] = False

In [15]: %timeit dill.loads(dill.dumps(g))
1000 loops, best of 3: 499 us per loop

In [16]:
```

Comment: Hi @Mike McKerns, when I started using `dill` it was for these custom `Python` classes that I instantiated that had many complicated data types inside and it worked perfectly (when `pickle` didn't).  I've been using `dill` since then but I'm wondering what types of data-types can I use `pickle` for that won't break? This might be out of the scope of a comment but I feel like you would be the expert since you made `dill` for a reason.

Comment: Look at https://github.com/uqfoundation/dill/blob/master/dill/_objects.py. It's my best effort to keep track of what can be pickled and what can't (by `dill` and/or `pickle`).  There's an associated test for this file as well.  Now, putting them inside classes… that's a bit more untested.