# why python's pickle is not serializing a method as default argument?

Tags: python, dictionary, lambda, pickle

I am trying to use pickle to transfer python objects over the wire between 2 servers. I created a simple class, that subclasses `dict` and I am trying to use pickle for the marshalling:

```
def value_is_not_none(value):
    return value is not None

class CustomDict(dict):
    def __init__(self, cond=lambda x: x is not None):
        super().__init__()
        self.cond = cond

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        if self.cond(value):
            dict.__setitem__(self, key, value)
```

I first tried to use `pickle` for the marshalling, but when I un-marshalled I received an error related to the `lambda` expression.

Then I tried to do the marshalling with `dill` but it seemed the `__init__` was not called.

Then I tried again with `pickle`, but I passed the `value_is_not_none()` function as the `cond` parameter - again the `__init__()` does not seemed to be invoked and the un-marshalling failed on the `__setitem__()` (`cond` is `None`).

Why is that? what am I missing here?

If I try to run the following code:

```
obj = CustomDict(cond=value_is_not_none)
obj['hello'] = ['world']

payload = pickle.dumps(obj, protocol=pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
obj2 = pickle.loads(payload)
```

it fails with

```
AttributeError: 'CustomDict' object has no attribute 'cond'
```

This is a different question than: [Python, cPickle, pickling lambda functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16626429/python-cpickle-pickling-lambda-functions)
as I tried using `dill` with `lambda` and it failed to work, and I also tried passing a function and it also failed.

Comment: Please list the non-working code with the traceback it gives

Comment: @holdenweb - take a look at the example i added and the output. thanks

Comment: @MartijnPieters - this is a different question than: [python-cpickle-pickling-lambda-functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16626429/python-cpickle-pickling-lambda-functions) as i tried using dill with lambda and it failed to work, and i also tried passing a function and it also failed - all stated in the question

Comment: Your second failure is not related to using functions; it is to do with pickle not calling the `CustomDict.__init__` method on unpickling, before `__setitem__` is called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pickle` is loading your dictionary data *before* it has restored the attributes on your instance. As such the `self.cond` attribute is not yet set when `__setitem__` is called for the dictionary key-value pairs.

Note that `pickle` will never call `__init__`; instead it'll create an entirely *blank* instance and restore the `__dict__` attribute namespace on that directly.

You have two options:

- default to `cond=None` and ignore the condition if it is still set to `None`:

  ```
  class CustomDict(dict):
      def __init__(self, cond=None):
          super().__init__()
          self.cond = cond

      def __setitem__(self, key, value):
          if getattr(self, 'cond', None) is None or self.cond(value):
              dict.__setitem__(self, key, value)
  ```

  The `getattr()` there is needed because a blank instance has no `cond` attribute at all (it is not set to `None`, the attribute is entirely missing). You could add `cond = None` to the class:

  ```
  class CustomDict(dict):
      cond = None
  ```

  and then just test for `if self.cond is None or self.cond(value):`.
- Define a custom [`__reduce__` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#object.__reduce__) to control how the initial object is created when restored:

  ```
  def _default_cond(v): return v is not None

  class CustomDict(dict):
      def __init__(self, cond=_default_cond):
          super().__init__()
          self.cond = cond

      def __setitem__(self, key, value):
          if self.cond(value):
              dict.__setitem__(self, key, value)

      def __reduce__(self):
          return (CustomDict, (self.cond,), None, None, iter(self.items()))
  ```

  `__reduce__` is expected to return a tuple with:

  - A callable that can be pickled directly (here the class does fine)
  - A tuple of positional arguments for that callable; on unpickling the first element is called passing in the second as arguments, so by setting this to `(self.cond,)` we ensure that the new instance is created with `cond` passed in as an argument and *now* `CustomDict.__init__()` *will* be called.
  - The next 2 positions are for a `__setstate__` method (ignored here) and for list-like types, so we set these to `None`.
  - The last element is an iterator for the key-value pairs that pickle then will restore for us.

  Note that I replaced the default value for `cond` with a function here too so you don't have to rely on `dill` for the pickling.