# How to Do Data Parallelization in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

So, I have 3 dimentional list. For example:

```
A=[[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]],...,[[2,4,1],[1,4,6],[1,2,4]]]
```

I want to process each 2 dimentional list in A independently but they all have same process. If I do it in sequence, I do:

```
for i in range(len(A)):
    A[i]=process(A[i])
```

But, it takes very long time. Could you tell me how to parallel compute by data parallelization in Python?

Comment: Parallelization requires threading. That requires a lot of work. Since lists are mutable, you'll likely have to create a copy for each individual thread (if I'm smart at programming). Copying/slicing the list will likely take more time than processing it in a single thread.

Comment: List of options here... https://wiki.python.org/moin/ParallelProcessing

Comment: @Zizouz212 so, there's no way that more efficient that processing it sequentially?

Comment: Threading in Python is actually not parallel at all and would slow things down, because the Global Interpreter Lock only executes one Python instruction at a time regardless of the number of threads. It's only suitable for doing something while waiting for I/O on another thread. True multiprocessing would work, but sharing the data requires locking and would also quite likely slow things down if there's a lot of writing to the array.

Comment: @cricket_007 Thanks, I'll try it.

Comment: @Jim Stewart if I made that list into part by myself like B=A[0:10], C=A[10:20], etc, could you tell me how to process B, C, etc at the same time?

Comment: @user7077941 My first choice would be to try to implement `process` with numpy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have multiple cores and processing each 2 dimensional list is expensive operation you could use [`Pool`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing) from [`multiprocessing`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing). Here's a short example that squares numbers in different process:

```
import multiprocessing as mp

A = [[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]],[[2,4,1],[1,4,6],[1,2,4]]]

def square(l):
    return [[x * x for x in sub] for sub in l]

pool = mp.Pool(processes=mp.cpu_count())
res = pool.map(square, A)

print res
```

Output:

```
[[[1, 4, 9], [16, 25, 36], [49, 64, 81]], [[4, 16, 1], [1, 16, 36], [1, 4, 16]]]
```

[`Pool.map`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.map) will behave like built-in `map` while splitting the iterable to worker processes. It also has third parameter called `chunksize` that defines how big chunks are submitted to workers.

Comment: Thank you very much! I'll try it later because my program still running sequentially since 30 minutes ago. So, I don't have to make A into some part and python will part it?

Comment: @user7077941 No, you don't have to split `A`. You might want to define third parameter called `chunksize` though depending on your data.

Comment: Wow, such a simple way. Thank you. ^^

Comment: Hi, I'm confused. I tried using your code but somehow error appeared "AttributeError" in with mp.Pool(processes=mp.cpu_count()) as pool. What should I do?

Comment: @user7077941 Didn't notice python 2.7 tag so I was running it with 3.5, I've edited the answer to work on Python 2.7.

Comment: Can I use lambda function? Or I must use named function?

Comment: @user7077941 You have to use named function since [lambdas can't be pickled](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16626429/python-cpickle-pickling-lambda-functions).